# Asp.net: unexpected Error-Handling - send mail and redirect to error.aspx?

Tags: asp.net, error-handling

in my very big webpage (aroung 50 pages, 20.000 line code) I have only a very few situations in which unexpected errors are possible, which I don't catch correctly.

But for my safty:
Is it possible, to send me an EMail (SMTP-Class is allready there, so I only must call a Method) and Redirect every unexpacted error to an specific site? (e.g.: Error.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In you Global.asax create an Application_Error method and handle errors there.  You can get the last exception using Server.GetLastError()

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use a custom error page that catches any unhandled errors. You can write code on that page to send you an error containing the exception details.

[Custom Error page](http://www.asp.net/hosting/tutorials/displaying-a-custom-error-page-cs)

Answer (score 1):

I believe a better way would be to write you own exception module and handler. Something in this fashion.

```
public sealed class ErrorCapture : IHttpModule
{

    #region IHttpModule Members

    public void Dispose()
    {
        //nothing here
    }

    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.Error += new EventHandler(context_Error);
    }

    void context_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Do your implementation like send mail
        // Get Required details and use response.write for 
        // a good error msg display
        HttpApplication Application = (HttpApplication)sender;
        HttpServerUtility Server = Application.Server;
        HttpResponse Response = Application.Response;

        Exception error = Server.GetLastError();
        if (error.GetType().Equals(typeof(HttpUnhandledException)))
            error = error.InnerException;

        //your stuff

        Server.ClearError();//Do this
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use customErrors for redirecting to the error page.

For sending a mail with a custom class, I've advise you to write a custom asp.net healthmonitoring provider.
Have a look at this article: http://www.tomot.de/en-us/article/6/asp.net/how-to-create-a-custom-healthmonitoring-provider-that-sends-e-mails
It shows you, how you can do that.